# Output number of iterations for Newton Method using Scipy

Tags: python, scipy, newtons-method, numerical-analysis

I would like to know how I can output the number of iterations when finding the root using Newtons method. I am calculating the root automatically using Scipy, so I wanted to know if there is a way of knowing how many iterations it took:

```
from spicy.optimize import newton
from math import *

f = lambda x : x**2 - sin(x)
ans = newton(f, 1, tol = 1.0E-8, maxiter = 100)
print(round(ans, 8))
```

Answer (score 1):

Spicy is a cool name for scipy. :)

Jokes aside, you simply need to include `full_output=True` in your call to `newton` (see the [doc](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.newton.html) for more detail). Executing your code, I got this output by printing ans:

```
(0.8767262153950625,       converged: True
           flag: 'converged'
 function_calls: 7
     iterations: 6
           root: 0.8767262153950625)
```

Comment: Hahah. typed in the code and I didn't notice the typo. Thanks for the solution!

Comment: @Prog101 No worries. Please feel free to upvote and accept the answer. :)